# How to apply palette to radpiechart?

Tags: xaml, telerik, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I have problems with RadPieChart. Always the radPieChart shows all series in the same color (Blue) and doesn't apply the DefaultPalette. The xaml code is the following:

```
     <telerik:RadPieChart x:Name="chartTipoGasto" Palette="{Binding DefaultPalette}" Grid.Row="3">
                        <telerik:PieSeries ItemsSource="{Binding}" RadiusFactor="0.9">
                            <telerik:PieSeries.ValueBinding>
                                <telerik:PropertyNameDataPointBinding PropertyName="Importe"></telerik:PropertyNameDataPointBinding>
                            </telerik:PieSeries.ValueBinding>
                            <telerik:PieSeries.LabelDefinitions>
                                <telerik:ChartSeriesLabelDefinition Margin="-7">
                                    <telerik:ChartSeriesLabelDefinition.Binding>
                                        <telerik:PropertyNameDataPointBinding PropertyName="Concepto"></telerik:PropertyNameDataPointBinding>
                                    </telerik:ChartSeriesLabelDefinition.Binding>
                                </telerik:ChartSeriesLabelDefinition>
                            </telerik:PieSeries.LabelDefinitions>
                        </telerik:PieSeries>
                    </telerik:RadPieChart>
```

I don't know why all series is displayed in blue and not in diferents colors like its show in demo projects that I download from Telerik website.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there actually something you're binding to with the Palette="{Binding DefaultPalette}" you have declared?

You can apply your own Palette like this (You change the Gradients to Solid brushes or I think even Images if you wanted) and add as many as you want.

```
<chart:RadChart.PaletteBrushes>
                                <RadialGradientBrush>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF010DBE"
                                        Offset="0" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF0659FD"
                                        Offset="0.5" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF0117CA"
                                        Offset="1" />
                                </RadialGradientBrush>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1"
                                    StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF029912"
                                        Offset="0" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF14FD22"
                                        Offset="0.492" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF03930C"
                                        Offset="1" />
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="#FFFCBA2A"/>
                                <RadialGradientBrush>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFDE9A05"
                                        Offset="0" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFF7AB05"
                                        Offset="0.5" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFDC8E03"
                                        Offset="1" />
                                </RadialGradientBrush>
</chart:RadChart.PaletteBrushes>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually I haven't anything in these binding, I thought This palette was in code behind . I just copy&paste from sample project.

RadControl isn't any predefined palettes?

I'm going to use your sample palette. How can I define palette in order to each one value in pie chart paint with different color?

Comment: Well, you can strip your Palette declaration since you're not actually binding to anything and the default colors should appear. The Telerik documentation should tell you everything about those color properties. As for the Palette example I provided, the value order follows the Brush order. So say you define Red/Blue as the only brushes in the palette. Then it will incrementally make them Red / Blue. If you use multiple like in my example, it will use them in order, then start over from the beginning once theyve all been used. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Yes, I think that you answer is useful for me, but I still don't implement this solution that you give me. One more question, I never found documentation about telerik rad pie chart and other rad metro style controls, where is this documentation?...

Comment: A good place to start would be here http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/radchart-overview.html and you might be more interested in the Styles and Templates section there.

Comment: Thanks again, but Today I found PaletteName Property for RadPieChart for Metro. With PaletteName="DefaultDark" the pie chart show each one values in chart with diferent color, using DefaultDark palette.